# How to toggle "Turn this device off to save power" in windows 11?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-11

I dont seem to have the option to disable the functionality "Turn this device off to save power" for my wifi network device. There used to be an option to toggle this in configuration field of the wireless  LAN card properties but it doesnt seem to be present. How can I make sure my Windows 11 PC is not disabling my wifi card for power management reasons?

Comment: What model is your wireless adapter?

Comment: Look in Device Manager, Network devices, pick out your card and disable the power saver feature there.

Answer (score 0):

There are many similar bugs in Windows sometimes related to Power Saving settings / Drivers.

1. `Start > Search > Device Manager > Networks Adapters > Double Click yours > Power Management Tab > uncheck: Turn this device off to save power`

If it's not there that is also a known issue.

2. Try updating your network adapter to the latest driver, usually from the manufacturers website
   or
3. Registry Edits may help (Export a backup / Create a restore point first):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-is-the-power-management-tab-missing-i-have/037105bc-6c46-4c50-b02c-91d6468fdcb1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/power-management-on-network-adapter

4. Powershell code:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/disable-netadapterpowermanagement?view=windowsserver2022-ps
5. You can also create a *Task Scheduler* task to Disable & Re-enable.
   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-need-to-disable-and-re-enable-my-wifi-adapter-to/7da1e814-b869-4392-bbef-963727181e19
6. If the reason is that you need to *Auto Reconnect WiFi* in Windows 11 (also a known issue) then create a similar Task to run a connection profile using: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html
   C:\Downloads\Nirsoft\wifiinfoview-x64\WifiInfoView.exe `/ConnectAP "SSID" "ID"`

`Trigger > On an event >  Log: Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational Source: NetworkProfile EventID: 10001`

10001 Network disconnect
10000 Network connect